# Magento 2 remove mini-cart content in cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart, headerlink

How can I remove Magento 2.3.1 minicart content in checkout_cart_index (cart page), but keeping cart header link and counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I've replaced in `Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml` :

this row : `if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):`

with this: `<?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar() && $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName() !== 'checkout_cart_index'): ?>`

Seams to work just fine.
Thank you